# Rotate ModelInstance at specific point

Tags: libgdx

How can i rotate ModelInstance at specific point( for example center of cube or corner of cube)

```
ModelInstance inst;

inst.transform.setToTranslation(cone.getX(),cone.getY(),cone.getZ())
        .rotate(Vector3.Y,cone.getTiltOnY()).rotate(Vector3.X,cone.getTiltOnX()).rotate(Vector3.X,90);
```

In my scenario i trying to rotate cone at its peek , but i rotate it in the middle. 
How i can set cone at coordinates as above, but rotate it at its peek.
I need to do something like that :

```
 Gdx.gl10.glPushMatrix();
 Gdx.gl10.glTranslatef(x,y,z);
 Gdx.gl10.glRotatef(angle,xaxis,yaxis,zaxis);
 mesh.render();
 Gdx.gl10.glPopMatrix();
```

But using ModelInstance API of libgdx.

Many thanks!

Comment: Rotating *around* a point is the same as translating to that point, rotating and then translating back. E.g.: `inst.transform.translate(-x, -y, -z).rotate(axis, angle).translate(x, y, z);`

Comment: Thanks, Xoppa. Great tutorials by the way:) Can you explain difference  between translate and setToTranslation?

Comment: It worked by the way. Problem solved.