# libGDX set rotation point 3D

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I have two objects base and weapon and I need to set rotate point of weapon to position of base.

```
public Test(){
position1 = new Vector3(0,0,0);
baseModel = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("data/models/tower/bases/base1.g3db", FileType.Internal));
        base = new Base(baseModel, position1);

        position2 = new Vector3(3,10,5);

        weaponModel = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("data/models/tower/weapons/weapon2.g3db", FileType.Internal));
        weapon = new Weapon(weaponModel, position2);
}
```

Here is update method

```
public void update(float delta){

        weapon.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, 45*(delta/2));
        base.transform.rotate(0, 1, 0, 45*(delta/2));
}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Thank you for answer

Comment: You want to rotate the `Weapon` arround the `Base`s center point? So you want to achieve what is shown in the second picture, instead of the thing in the first picture right?

Comment: Yes, change rotate point of 2. object to 1. object point. Rotate 2. object around first one.

Comment: @Xoppa s comment under this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939393/rotate-modelinstance-at-specific-point) question should be the solution for your problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That's it. :)

Solution: weapon.transform.translate(3, 0, 0).rotate(0,1,0, 45*delta).translate(-3, 0, 0);

Comment: @JakubKučera why don't you post this as your (own) answer?  it might help others.  Answering your own question is encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rotation around a point is the same as translating to that point, rotating and then translating back.
So this process consists of 3 steps:

1. Translate to the `rotationPoint`, for example `translate(3, 0, 0)`
2. Rotate arround the center (which is now the `rotationPoint`), for example `rotate(0,1,0, 45*delta)`
3. Translate back (the translation is relative to the rotation), for example `translate(-3, 0, 0);`

In this case the code then looks like this:

```
weapon.transform.translate(3, 0, 0).rotate(0,1,0, 45*delta).translate(-3, 0, 0);
```