# How to rotate part of a 3D model about its center, not the model's centre with LIBGDX

Tags: rotation, libgdx, coordinates, nodes

I have a model created in Blender with a ship with one turret, and the turret has 1 gun.
Just to be clear these are 3 separate objects in blender.
In the g3dj file this appears as 3 nodes: one for the ship, one for the turret, one for the gun.

```
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": "gun1", 
        "rotation": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107,  0.707107], 
        "scale": [ 0.100000,  0.984755,  0.100000], 
        "translation": [-3.526966,  1.428384,  0.191505], 
        "parts": [
            {
                "meshpartid": "Cylinder_part1", 
                "materialid": "gunMaterial"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "turret1", 
        "scale": [ 1.000000,  0.300000,  0.395389], 
        "translation": [-1.603167,  1.406584,  0.000000], 
        "parts": [
            {
                "meshpartid": "Cube.001_part1", 
                "materialid": "turretMaterial"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ship", 
        "scale": [ 3.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000], 
        "parts": [
            {
                "meshpartid": "Cube_part1", 
                "materialid": "shipMaterial", 
                "uvMapping": [[]]
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"animations": []
```

}

Using Libgdx I try to rotate the turret through say 30 degrees (rotAngle=30).
So I translate to what I think is the model's origin (I presume that is the origin of the ship?).
Then I rotate. Then finally I would translate back.
But I have taken that translate out because the rotate is not around the correct point?
Code is as follows (based on a xoppa tutorial):

```
        Vector3 dimensions = new Vector3();

    for (int i = 0; i < model.nodes.size; i++) {
        String id = model.nodes.get(i).id;
        ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(model, id);
        instance.transform.getTranslation(position);

        Node node = instance.getNode(id);
        node.calculateLocalTransform();
        node.localTransform.getTranslation(position);
        node.calculateBoundingBox(bounds).mul(node.localTransform);
        node.localTransform.getScale(scale);
        bounds.getDimensions(dimensions);
        centre=bounds.getCenter(centre);
        //float radius;
        //radius = dimensions.x / 2f;

        if (id.equals("ship")) {
            ///instance.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y,rotAngle);
            ship = instance;
            instances.add(ship);
            continue;
        }
        if (id.startsWith("gun")) {

            guns.add(instance);
            instances.add(instance);
            continue;
        }
        if (id.startsWith("turret")) {
            //movement on Y is based on Z from blender
            instance.transform.trn(-centre.x,-centre.z,0).
            rotate(Vector3.Y,rotAngle); // ???z???

            turrets.add(instance);
            instances.add(instance);
            continue;
        }
    }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating all those renderables?

Comment: yet once you tell them to do there is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656334/libgdx-set-rotation-point-3d; the key is to translate back on your pivot point, rotate and translate back

Comment: @Xoppa sorry only just seen the replies. I was following your tutorial that uses renderables at the time!

Comment: @cfrick thanks. I know that is the theory but I still have a problem. I think I need to restate the question.

Comment: @xoppa I have reset my code/question. Can you have another look please?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea was right, but I needed to translate using the position (translation) of the node not the centre, and take into account the scale factor from blender, and the apparent random switching of some y/z values.

Here is the modified code for the turret:

```
Vector3 turretMove = new Vector3();                
turretMove.x = position.x*scale.x;
//scale.z is what was the blender scale.y and vice versa
turretMove.y = -position.y*scale.z; //using opposite sign of position
turretMove.z = position.z*scale.y;
instance.transform.translate(turretMove.x,turretMove.y,turretMove.z).
rotate(Vector3.Y,dt).
translate(-turretMove.x,-turretMove.y,-turretMove.z);
```

This code now includes the translate back to the original position.
It took several hours of trial and error to get here!

In Blender Z-up was from the bottom to the top of the ship, and Y from the left side of the ship (and turret) to the right.

In Libgdx, Z was from the left side of the ship to the right (looking into the screen) with Y being from the bottom to the top of the ship (up the screen).

Export from Blender was to FBX with -Z forward and Y Up with only selected objects exported.

I guess some of this explains the flipping of the Z and Y scale values?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX#setting-the-coordinate-system-up-axis

Comment: Follow @Xoppa link. In short: in Blender export to FBX using scale 0.01 (default is 1.0 resulting 100x bigger models). Then, use fbx-conv with '-f' parameter. This will fix Blender axis for libGDX.