# Positioning of objects taking object's left-top as point instead of object's center in LibGDX

Tags: 3d, libgdx, position

Kindly Help! I am so stucked-up.
I have a model in g3db format. I want to proper position this in 3D space in XZ-plane taking left-top corner as center. So that when i enter code:
`MyObject.transform.setTranslation(0, MyObject.getTranslation(new Vector3(0,0,0)).y, 0);`
The object got placed at origin.

I can't use:
`MyObject.transform.setTranslation(objectWidth / 2, MyObject.getTranslation(new Vector3(0,0,0)).y, objectLength / 2;`
Because there may be some initial rotation in the g3db object which can interfere with confusion in which is width and which is Length.

Here is the supporting image:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqKfD.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would using the answer found in this question be useful?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674904/4922000

> Jakub Kučera
>
> 1. Translate to the rotationPoint, for example translate(3, 0, 0)
> 2. Rotate arround the center (which is now the rotationPoint), for example rotate(0,1,0, 45*delta)
> 3. Translate back (the translation is relative to the rotation), for example translate(-3, 0, 0);
>
> object.transform.translate(3, 0, 0).rotate(0,1,0, 45*delta).translate(-3, 0, 0);

If that conflicts with your existing rotation code then you could try physically moving your object in your 3d authoring software (Blender?) before exporting to .fbx and then .g3db .

I personally use Blender, and moving your object so your preferred pivot point is laying at 0,0,0 world space in blender works for me.