# libgdx how to slowly rotate a model to face a point

Tags: android, vector, rotation, libgdx

Hi i am trying to make a libgdx game...but i am stuck on how to rotate a model instance to face another but slowly like 1 or 2 degrees per second

I have two vectors the direction of the first model instance and the position of the second

Comment: Pseudocode: rotation+=rotationSpeed*deltaTime where rotationSpeed is 1 (-1) or 2 (-2) degrees per second. And use if statement to check if no more rotation is necessary. Note: we won't write game for you so build your answer "I tried this code ** code ** but it doesn't work. Can you help me to find out why." instead of "How to ..."

Comment: But my main problem is finding the specific axis to rotate with

Comment: Do you work with 3D?

Comment: do not know if this is what you want,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939393/rotate-modelinstance-at-specific-point but you can look, also you can use the search box stackoverflow there several similar answers maybe find one that meets your question

Comment: Yes i work with 3d and thanks Angel angel