# LibGDX 3D rotation on Sphere

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, rotation, geometry

I am building a game where your character walks on a planet. I want to make it that the character lags will always face toward the planet center (0,0,0). I found one point in space where I like the rotation of the character, and now I want to keep it when his location is changed.

I got Matrix4 transform, I want to translate it and keep the rotation toward the point 0,0,0. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to rotate around a specific point then translate to that point, rotate and then translate the same amount back. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Xoppa I don't understand why are pointing me there. My question is more complicated than rotating around a point. I read your tutorials and the demo code about bullet, several times. Also I saw many previous answers and [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939393/rotate-modelinstance-at-specific-point#comment33248639_21939393) of yours. I don't want just to rotate, I want to keep my direction to the center of earth(0,0,0) when I do translation.

Comment: If you want to set the direction to the center of the earth then you can do: `direction.set(position).sub(centerOfEarth).nor();`. If that doesn't help then consider including the code (http://sscce.org) that you already have. You can't expect for someone trying to help you to guess what your code looks like and what you're working with. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.